# Join data sets which have several lines assigned to table key - How to prevent Qty duplication?

Tags: pandas, join

I have a question about the best way to join below datasets.

Data Set 1:

```html
Order Material Qty
5111 chair 4
5111 table 1
5111 book 3
6222 chair 4
6222 table 1
```

Data Set 2:

```html
Order Customer Type Customer ID
5111 Sold-to 222
5111 Ship-to 333
5111 Payer 444
6222 Sold-to 555
6222 Ship-to 777
6222 Payer 888
```

Data Set after Join:

```html
Order Material Qty Customer Type Customer ID
5111 chair 4 Sold-to 222
5111 chair 4 Ship-to 333
5111 chair 4 Payer 444
5111 table 1 Sold-to 222
5111 table 1 Ship-to 333
5111 table 1 Payer 444
5111 book 3 Sold-to 222
5111 book 3 Ship-to 333
5111 book 3 Payer 444
6222 chair 4 Sold-to 555
6222 chair 4 Ship-to 777
6222 chair 4 Payer 888
6222 table 1 Sold-to 555
6222 table 1 Ship-to 777
6222 table 1 Payer 888
```

I think that this is a common problem, where two datasets which have several lines linked to the same table key (order) need to be joined.

However, when having quantities involved, how can I prevent having quantity duplication issue after the join?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

*taking `df` and `df1` as the dataframe names*

```
df.combine_first(df1)

  Customer  Customer.1  ID Material   Order  Qty   Type
0  Sold-to         NaN NaN    chair  5111.0  4.0  222.0
1  Ship-to         NaN NaN    table  5111.0  1.0  333.0
2    Payer         NaN NaN     book  5111.0  3.0  444.0
3  Sold-to         NaN NaN    chair  6222.0  4.0  555.0
4  Ship-to         NaN NaN    table  6222.0  1.0  777.0
5    Payer         NaN NaN      NaN  6222.0  NaN  888.0
```